# Do We Need a Procurement Tag?

Tags: discussion

Doing a search for "contract" shows a number of questions where I think 'procurement' adds/provides a better definition:
https://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=contract

However the number is probably less than five; is it ok to jump the gun here? Or is that creating unnecessary/unclear direction?

Been thinking a lot about terminology/search lately, not just on here but on other portals/datasets that I use/contribute to. Perhaps creating a dictionary/thesaurus for metadata about linked open data is ideal here?
Perhaps that has already been done?
Perhaps this is not a good idea in general?